# Create a tensor inside an autographable function based on input tensor's shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

Consider following program:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# @tf.function
def make_matrix(a):
    N = tf.shape(a)[0]
    A = tf.zeros([2*N, 2*N], dtype=a.dtype)
    return A

a = np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype=np.float32)
A = make_matrix(a)
print(A.numpy())
```

This executes as expected. However if the `@tf.function` decorator is uncommented it aborts with an error:

```
(python39) C:\Users\Anonymous\tfproject>python tftest.py
2021-07-11 20:47:10.973996: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-07-11 20:47:10.974887: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\tfproject\tftest.py", line 11, in <module>
    A = make_matrix(a)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 763, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3279, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 986, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
NotImplementedError: in user code:

    C:\Users\Anonymous\tfproject\tftest.py:7 make_matrix  *
        A = tf.zeros([2*N, 2*N], dtype=a.dtype)
    C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py:2911 wrapped
        tensor = fun(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py:2960 zeros
        output = _constant_if_small(zero, shape, dtype, name)
    C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py:2896 _constant_if_small
        if np.prod(shape) < 1000:
    <__array_function__ internals>:5 prod

    C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:3030 prod
        return _wrapreduction(a, np.multiply, 'prod', axis, dtype, out,
    C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:87 _wrapreduction
        return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
    C:\Users\Anonymous\Apps\miniconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:867 __array__
        raise NotImplementedError(

    NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (mul:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Is there a way to declare a dynamically shaped tensor inside a function and have it autographed?
How are dynamically shaped tensors supposed to be allocated in autograph-enabled functions?

Comment: The code snippet above does not reproduce the error on Colab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you are passing to `tf.zeros` a list of `tf.Tensor`.
From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros), you can read that the `shape` passed to `tf.zeros` has to be

> A list of integers, a tuple of integers, or a 1-D Tensor of type int32.

Thus, you should replace the list of `tf.Tensor` with a single `tf.Tensor` that can be created with `tf.stack`.

The code below works

```
@tf.function
def make_matrix(a):
    N = tf.shape(a)[0]
    shape = tf.stack([2*N, 2*N], axis=0)
    A = tf.zeros(shape, dtype=a.dtype)
    return A
```